# An error occurred when importing the plug-in Canvai in unity: Reference has errors 'Google.Protobuf'. How to solve it

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

An error occurred when importing the plug-in Canvai in unity: Assembly 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll' will not be loaded due to errors: Reference has errors 'Google.Protobuf'. How to solve it?

Try to open the project with Visual Studio, the "Google.Protobuf" package will be automatically downloaded and installed through the NuGet package manager, but there is no item in the "Default Project" drop-down menu in the "Package Manager Console", and the command cannot be used to add the Google.Protobuf package. Also there is no option to "Manage NuGet Packages" after right clicking on the project in the Solution Explorer window.